# Function f is bounded on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: calculus, continuity, bounded-variation

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to R$ be continuous such that $lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0$.

How can I Prove that f is bounded on $[0, \infty)$.

I know that condition for a function to be bounded is -  There exists a real number M such that  $|f(x)| \leq M$ , for all x in X(domain).

Comment: How can you take the limit when $\;x\to+\infty\;$ if the function's defined **only** on $\;[0,1)\;$ ??

Comment: @timbuc Sorry, I made changes. It is $f: [0, \infty) \to R $

Comment: My answer , mutatis mutandis, remains true .

Comment: But you did that for $x \to 1^{-}$

Comment: That is part of the "mutatis mutandis" part: change that to $\;x\to\infty\;$ , and etc.

Comment: @Timbuc I edited your answer. Have a look and let me know that it is correct ?

Comment: No, it isn't correct and I rolled back the edition to its original form. I added a short explanation...and I wonder how come those who approved the editing did so. Apparently they even didn't bother to read things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** ...the intention was to take the limit when $\;x\to 1^-\;$ , then:

Take, say $\;\epsilon=0.1\;$ , and since $\;f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 1^-]{}0\;$ , there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t

$$1-x<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon=0.1$$

But also $\;f\;$ is bounded on $\;[0\,,\,\,1-\epsilon=0.9]\;$ by Weierstrass thorem, thus all in all...

For $\;x\to \infty\;$ As above, there exists $\;R\in\Bbb R^+\;$ s.t.

$$x>R\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$$

and $\;f\;$ is bounded in $\;[0,R]\;$ ...

Comment: Weierstrass thorem=EVT?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what EVT is, but Weierestrass (first) theorem says that a continuous function in a *closed, bounded interval* (or in a compact set , in more general setups) is bounded there. The second says such a function attains both its maximum and minimum within the compact set.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what are 1st and 2nd theorems, but the second one you've cited is exactly EVT (Extreme Value Theorem)